# Mouseover Grayscale not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am having some issues with a mouseover state in IE9 and was hoping someone could help me.

This element will be various sizes and so that is why I am reluctant to use a background image sprite.

My issue is when I hover on the item the image turns grey, however when I hover on the tick in the middle the gray scale effect is lost, as I am guessing IE9 thinks that I am no longer hovering on the item, when I am.

http://www.tindlemanor.co.uk/jtest/cameron/11.html

I have played about with the mouse over example on jquery and it works in IE9, so I am guesing I am doing something a bit stupid.

It works in all other browsers, including ie8 and ie7, if this happened in 7 then I could understand it and simply let it slide, however the fact that its in 9, means I need to address this.

Thanking everyone in advance.

Cameron

Comment: I see you tried using mouseenter/mouseleave events in your code, but it’s commented out – why, did this not work as expected? Those events are actually the one to prefer – because mouseover/mouseout already fire when you hover over a child element, which is not what you want here.

Comment: I tried to use mouseenter/mouseleave, however it didnt appear to work for me, I also tried the hover state, mouse in and out and sadly nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by a conflict between the `:hover` pseudo class in the CSS and the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events in the jQuery. I think I have found a solution to the background losing the filter when you hover over the green tick though:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veewx/3/)**

Appears to work in IE9 and Chrome still. The JSFiddle doesn't work in Firefox, but I think that's down to other reasons.

I basically restructured the jQuery `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events into a `hover()` event (I doubt this made the difference) and commented out the lines that set `opacity` properties in the `.grayscale` class.

Have a look in IE9 and let me know what you think.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".inspire-me").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("on");
    //  $(this).find('.grayscale').css('opacity', '0.50');
        $(this).find('.content-lower').css('opacity', '1');
        var margin = $(this).find('.grayscale').height() / 2;
        var half = margin - 17;
        $(this).find('.hide').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.hide').css({'top' : half});
    }
    ,
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("on");
    //  $(this).find('.grayscale').css('opacity', '1');
        $(this).find('.hide').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I have got this working in Firefox now by specifying the full SVG XML in the `filter` property in the CSS:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veewx/3/)**

Comment: It appears to be working fine in IE9, thank you very much. I will do some further investigating as to why its not working in Firefox

Comment: No worries, you're making progress! If this answer has helped, please could you set it as Accepted? Many thanks :)